# access values in json, specially through ROR

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4

```
    "divisions":{
      "ocd-division/country:us/state:co/place:aurora":{
       "name":"Aurora city",
       "scope":"citywide",
       "officeIds":[
          "O0",
          "O1"]
    }}
```

I am using Google Civic Information API to get representive information. let's say this is a part of JSON generated by Google and I want to access its elements but the issue is - i cant use "**ocd-division/country:us/state:co/place:aurora**" as a key, because its dynamically generated by Google.

If I search for some different address like India, the key will be different from "**ocd-division/country:us/state:co/place:aurora**" to something else(instead of 'us', there would be 'in'), So please suggest the way I should access in this case the value.

Please clarify if you don't understand question or need more clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the json to a hash:

```
parsed_data = JSON.parse google_data
```

then either iterate over all divisions:

```
parsed_data['divisions'].each do |division_key, division_info|
  # do something with each division
end
```

or get only the first one:

```
division_key, division_info = parsed_data['divisions'].first
```

Use this if you want parse the key as well:

```
more_info = division_key.split('/').inject(Hash.new) do |hash, key_part|
  if key_part.include? ":" 
    key, value = key_part.split ":"
    hash[key] = value
  end
  hash
end
```

Now you can access it via `more_info['country']`